# Using group argument in aes() in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, bar-chart

I am trying to use the "group" argument in aes() in ggplot2, and I am not sure why it is not working as I currently have it.

I would like an image that groups my "maskalthalf" variable in the way that this image uses "sex" (found [here](https://sebastiansauer.github.io/percentage_plot_ggplot2_V2/)).

[image]

This is what my graph currently looks like.

[image]

This is the code I have so far.

```
ggplot(groups, aes(x = message, y = mean, group = factor(maskalthalf))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.5, fill = "003900") +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(mean, digits = 1), vjust = -2)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - se, ymax = mean + se), width = .2, position = position_dodge(.9)) + 
  labs(title = "Evaluations of Personal and General Convincingness") + 
  ylab("Rating") + 
  xlab("Personal evaluation or general evaluation") + 
  ylim(0, 8)
```

This is a sketch of what I am aiming for:

[image]

Data:

```
structure(list(maskalthalf = c("High", "High", "Low", "Low"), 
    message = c("General", "Personal", "General", "Personal"), 
    mean = c(4.79090909090909, 6.38181818181818, 4.69879518072289, 
    4.8433734939759), se = c(0.144452868727642, 0.104112130946133, 
    0.149182255019704, 0.180996951567937)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), groups = structure(list(maskalthalf = c("High", "Low"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1:2, 3:4), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1:2, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image in your first example uses facets to group by variable. So you could try that:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x = message, y = mean)) + 
  geom_col(width = 0.5, fill = "003900") +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(mean, digits = 1), vjust = -2)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - se, ymax = mean + se), width = .2, position = position_dodge(.9)) + 
  labs(title = "Evaluations of Personal and General Convincingness") + 
  ylab("Rating") + 
  xlab("Personal evaluation or general evaluation") + 
  ylim(0, 8) +
  facet_wrap(~maskalthalf)
```

[image]